# Building different project versions from the same source code branch

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying to build my Java project into two different version, each one based on different versions on the same dependencies. Specifically, my project A requires a dependency B, which has two different versions (e.g. v1 and v2). I am looking to build project A with each dependency version of B and get as artifact two different jars: A-v1.jar and A-v2.jar. The source code is the same so I wouldn't want to duplicate it into two different Maven projects, as I am looking to scale it when new versions of B will be released.

What I have tried so far: I defined two build profiles v1 and v2 where I have specified the dependency B version. This works fine as I can build the two profiles, but the issue is that I have no idea how to tell Maven to add a version number to the build artifact. It always builds project A into A-1.0.jar, where 1.0 is the project A version in the pom.

**One update of my investigation:** I have added a finalName element in the build section of my parent pom to override the default artifacts naming. Now the naming will be like ${artifactId}-${project.version.mycustomver}, where project.version.mycustomver property is defined in each build profiles. This seems to generate the correct naming of jars, however maven-install-plugin is changing the artifacts names back to ${artifactId}-${version}. No idea why and how to avoid it.

I appreciate any suggestion. Thanks,
DanP

Comment: You can simply define the dependency as `<scope>provided</scope>` and you will create only a single artifact. The user of your lib can simply decided by added the appropriate version of the dependency which is used. No need having different versions of your own artifact etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `classifier` which is somehow made for that.

But you should also be able to change the `version` using a property that is overridden in the profiles.

Since you need two distinct POMs, one per "version" of your project, you in fact need two projects. However, you can have one normal version A. And a second one which is empty but uses dependency management to exclude and replace the dependencies that changes from A-v1 to A-v2.

Comment: I will check about classifier. I already used a property for the module version. However, while the build is fine, the generated pom file (that resides in Nexus repository with the generated artifact) will carry on the property instead of the value of it. So when I will use A-v1.jar as a dependency in another project, the build will fail since it won't find the pom definition.

Comment: Even with classifier, you will have a single POM for the two projects.

Comment: Not sure I understand your second suggestion about using two projects. Wouldn't I need to duplicate the source code in both projects? I definitely want to avoid this.

Comment: No you can have a second project (A2) without any source. It simply define a dependency on previous project (A1) + a dependency management section in order to change the version of the transitive dependencies (i.e. dependencies of A1) that needed to be changed in project A2.